# How to configure UTF-8 in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I using Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production Version 19.15.2.0.0.

I'm writing a query that displays in Korean, but when I copy the query into Oracle, the system displays text in a different format.

original:

> SELECT '안녕하세요' FROM dual;

after copying to Oracle:

> SELECT '?????' FROM dual;

how can I configure that in Oracle?

Comment: what tool are you using: copying a query to "oracle" does not mean anything. If you're copying it to a sqlplus session connected to oracle, then the problem is with your terminal setting, not oracle.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Region settings -> Change Region format to Korean (Korea)
2. Select Korean keyboard mode when copy/paste query from text editor to Oracle
3. Done